# My sliding navigation divs in jQuery are buggy

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I just started learning jQuery/javascript a few days ago, I like to learn by doing, and I created these divs that slide for navigation. They look good at first, but if I keep navigating around they get buggy looking after a couple of clicks.

```
var home=$(".navHome");
home.mouseover(function(){
  home.animate({
   left:'30px',
   top:'25px',
   opacity:'0.75',
   });
  });
home.mouseout(function(){
 home.animate({
  left:'25px',
  top:'25px',
  opacity:'1',
 });
});
home.mouseover(function(){
  home.addClass("orangeText");
});
home.mouseout(function(){
  home.removeClass("orangeText");
});
```

Is there a way to streamline this so it works better? Also when my mouse goes back and forth over the div a couple times quickly, it's like the div starts spasming back and forth. Is there a way to put something in that prevents that sort of thing from happening? Thanks!

Comment: you can prevent the movement queue with home.is(":animated"). check if home is animated with this and only act if it is not. http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `home.animate()` use `home.stop().animate()`.

Using `stop()` prevents the animations from queuing one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

When you move mouse back and forth you are queuing up additional animations. To prevent this use `stop()` method

```
home.mouseover(function(){
  home.stop(true,true)animate({/* settings*/})
})
```

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

If $.animate().stop() is still stacking up animation queues, then use $.css() because it is about 10x faster in rendering